# While loop executes only once

Tags: java, while-loop

I have a hard time figuring out why the while loop won't actually loop.  It runs through once and stops.

```
import java.util.*;

public class mileskm {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean continue1 = true;

        while (continue1 == true) {

            System.out.println("Would you like to convert m-km or km-m(km for m-km and m for km-m)");

            String convert = inp.nextLine();
            if (convert.equalsIgnoreCase("km")) {
                System.out.println("Enter the mileage to be converted.");
                double num = inp.nextDouble();
                double con = num * 1.60934;
                System.out.println(con);
                continue1 = true;
            } else if (convert.equalsIgnoreCase("m")) {
                System.out.println("Enter the km to be converted.");
                double num = inp.nextDouble();
                double con = num * 0.621371;
                System.out.println(con);
                continue1 = true;
            } else {
                continue1 = false;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to make it loop so the user would be able to convert units more than once. Any and all help is welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you call `nextDouble()`, it consumes the number but not the newline that comes after the number. To fix this, simply put a line of code `inp.nextLine();` after calling `nextDouble()`.

---

Example and full explanation:

Suppose your input "km", press enter, "123", press enter. Then from the program's point of view, the input stream is `"km\n123\n"`.

The code `String convert = inp.nextLine();` gets the value `"km"` and also advances the input past the first `"\n"`.

The code `double num = inp.nextDouble();` gets the string `"123"` and returns the value (double)123.0 . It stops parsing when it sees the `'\n'`, but it does not consume the character - it remains in the input buffer.

In the next iteration of the loop, `inp.nextLine();` sees `"\n"` immediately, so the `String convert = "";`. This triggers the `else` case in your loop, so it exits the loop.

Answer (score 1):

If either of the two conditions:

```
(convert.equalsIgnoreCase("km"))
```

or

```
(convert.equalsIgnoreCase("m"))
```

... is not `true`, you set your `boolean` `continue1` to `false`, which will break your loop at the next iteration.

Please also note that since it's a boolean, you can (and should) write your `while` statement as such:

```
while (continue1) {
  // etc.
}
```

Note also that you should try/catch for `Exception`s when you scan for specific types, e.g. `Scanner.nextDouble`, as this might very well break your code with a stack trace if the input is of an unexpected type.

Comment: I don't understand how to deal with that last else {continue1 = false}... because if it anything other than m or km I want it to close.

Comment: Never mind.  I figured that out.  Now I have another problem, that occurs very often in any program I make.  Once it goes through the loop once, the line

ystem.out.println("Would you like to convert m-km or km-m(km for m-km and m for km-m)");

then prints twice on the second run and every run after.  What makes it print twice everytime after first loop?

Comment: It shouldn't print twice per loop with that code... of course it will reprint (once), once the loop iterates.

Answer (score 1):

There is still one problem in your code intialize your scanner object in your while loop, it will resolve your problem of printing the line 2 times. Use This

```
import java.util.*;

public class mileskm {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner inp;
    boolean continue1 = true;

    while (continue1) {

        System.out.println("Would you like to convert m-km or km-m(km for m-km and m for km-m)");
       inp = new Scanner(System.in);

        String convert = inp.nextLine();
        if (convert.equalsIgnoreCase("km")) {
            System.out.println("Enter the mileage to be converted.");
            double num = inp.nextDouble();
            double con = num * 1.60934;
            System.out.println(con);
            continue1 = true;
        } else if (convert.equalsIgnoreCase("m")) {
            System.out.println("Enter the km to be converted.");
            double num = inp.nextDouble();
            double con = num * 0.621371;
            System.out.println(con);
            continue1 = true;
        } else {
            break;
        }

    }
}
}
```

Kindly Check It
This Is the answer of your question written in comments

Answer (score 0):

use

```
String convert = inp.next();
```

instead of

```
String convert = inp.nextLine();
```

nextLine() is reading empty line because of System.out.println().