# Beginner trying to program a simple calculator

Tags: java, exception

I just started Java and was trying to program a simple calculator:

I tried the following:

```
    double x, y; //inputs
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("x?");
    x = sc.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("y?");
    y = sc.nextDouble();

    double answer = 0;

    System.out.println("Operation type: (+,-,*,/)");


    String opStr= sc.nextLine();
    char op = opStr.charAt(0);


    switch(op)
    {
        case '+':
            answer=x+y;
            break;

        case '-':
            answer=x-y;
            break;

        case '*':
            answer=x*y;
            break;

        case '/':

            if (y==0)
            {
                System.out.println("Error, can't divide by zero");
            }
            else
            {
                answer=x/y;
            }

            break;
        default: System.out.println("Unkown operation");
    }  // switch end

    System.out.println("answer = " +x+op+y+"=" + answer);
```

When I try to run it I get the following: (I can input x and y, but afterwards I get the error message.

```
Operation type: (+,-,*,/)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:686)
    at edf_1.EDF_1.main(EDF_1.java:170)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 seconds)
```

Would be really grateful if anyone can help me find the mistake or issue!

Thanks

NaC

Comment: Are you emptying the buffer after taking `x` and `y`? If not, the `nextLine()` will do that for you, and an empty line will be assigned to `opStr`, so `charAt(0)` will fire an exception.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18163518/while-loop-executes-only-once/18163608#18163608

Comment: Also, start with: `String result = "Answer = " + x + "" + op + "" + y + "=" + answer;
System.out.println(result);`

Answer (score 8):

[`nextDouble()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble%28%29) **doesn't** handle the end of the line. So when you call [`nextLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29) again, it'll take as input the *enter* (`\n`) you entered before. So it's skipping the actual input and swallows the `\n` from the previous input that was missed by `nextLine()`. You should call another `nextLine()` before the real `nextLine()` (So it will swallow the `\n`).

If you don't want to do that, you should construct another `Scanner` rather than using the same object.

That's the reason of your [`StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringIndexOutOfBoundsException.html), `opStr` is only a `\n` at this point.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, after reading the double, the scanner input is not empty. Thus, the invocation of `nextLine()` returns immediately, returning the part of the last input that was not parseable as a floating-point value (which may be empty). If you invoke `sc.nextLine()` before asking for the operation, the next call to `sc.nextLine()` reads the line containing your operation.

Answer (score 0):

I built the world's simplest calculator when i began learning java. This should work fine for you :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CalculatorProgram {
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int N1;
int N2;
int O = 0;
System.out.println("Enter the first number:");
N1 = scan.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter the second number:");
N2 = scan.nextInt();
System.out.println("Press 1 for addition, 2 for subtraction, 3 for multiplication, 4 for       division
O=scan.nextInt();
switch (O){
case 1:
O=N1+N2;
System.out.println(O);
break;
case 2:
O=N1-N2;
System.out.println(O);
break;
case 3:
O=N1*N2;
System.out.println(O);
break;
case 4:
O=N1/N2;
System.out.println(O);
break;

default:
System.out.println("That is an invalid selection. Thank you for using this program.");
break;

} 
}

}
```

Youre welcome.