# System.out.println not working for string

Tags: java, string

I'm trying to learn Java through Hackerrank and the challenge that I'm working on currently takes an int, double, and string and prints them on separate lines in reverse order, but I haven't been able to get the string to print.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
            int x=sc.nextInt();
            double y=sc.nextDouble();
            String s=sc.nextLine();

            System.out.println("String: "+s);
            System.out.println("Double: "+y);
            System.out.println("Int: "+x);
         }
    }
```

The input is:

```
42
3.1415
Welcome to Hackerrank Java tutorials!
```

And output is:

```
String:
Double: 3.1415
Int: 42
```

I don't know Java at all, but from the code I've seen online, I can't tell why this is wrong.

Comment: Related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19077908/beginner-trying-to-program-a-simple-calculator/19077970#19077970

Comment: Related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18163518/while-loop-executes-only-once/18163608#18163608

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the first part of the code to this:

```
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = sc.nextInt();
        double y = sc.nextDouble();
        sc.nextLine();  // Discard rest of current line
        String s = sc.nextLine();
```

The way `java.util.Scanner` splits the input into numbers or lines is a bit weird.

Comment: It works! Why is that only necessary for the string and not the others?

Answer (score -1):

The `sc.nextLine();` should instead be `sc.next();`

Comment: There is no `nextln()`, and `next()` does not solve the problem.

Comment: .next() works fine for what they are trying to do. It will return the next token entered as a String.

Comment: What if the string line contains spaces?